# UnsatisfiedLinkError when adding .so files to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to include https://github.com/GerardSoleCa/Robosodium in my android studio project. I'm running Android studio 1.4.1

I created a jniLibs folder with the compiled .so files. I initializsed the library in my main activity like this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libkaliumjni");
}
```

when I run the project I get this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/be.example.libtest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/be.example.libtest-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblibkaliumjni.so"
```

My folder structure is:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

EDIT:

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.example.libtest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: try adding ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }    line in defaultconfig block in gradle file

Comment: Still the same error;

Comment: Can you put your build.gradle file? This file configures the path to load .so libraries... Also, i could be useful check where, in your code, put the `System.loadLibrary`

Comment: I was getting the same error for aviary library usage  in some devices. That line helped me

Comment: I did not use System.loadLibrary

Comment: I edited my question with the build.gradle file as it was without the ndk line.

Comment: If you took a look to the error it sais liblibkaliumjni.so but the file are called libkaliumjni and the loadfunction defines that name correct. How is this possible :s

Comment: try
 static {
    System.loadLibrary("kaliumjni");
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.loadLibrary(...) couldn't find native library in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libkaliumjni");
}
```

to this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("kaliumjni");
}
```

Comment: It's not weird, by convention the 'lib' prefix is automatically added ;)

Comment: Hey, I'm getting the same error as op, but I have the correct loadLibrary spelling. I checked the apk, and for some reason the .so's aren't in there. One difference between our errors though is that my Android.mk is generating a libs folder, instead of a jniLibs folder.