# Unable to run the apk having .so (Shared Object) file

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have followed all the steps mentioned in this answer([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523384/424413)).

But still I am getting the same **Unsatisfied Link Error** as shown below.

> 11-11 12:38:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(19180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-11 12:38:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mAdd

Here's the screen shot of our app which obtained from 
[Native Libs Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app)

PS: We have generated the .so file using NDK build from Android instead of cygwin64.

Could you please convey me what is the real problem here ?

[image]

**== Update ==**

Please go through the following image

Inside libAddition.so file,

native method `public native int mAdd(int v1,int v2)`; is declared in Addition.java file.

Header file is generated, for this java file using javah which contains this declaration,

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_testsampleso_Addition_mAdd
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);
```

Here, my question is

why method signature or Entry point `Java_com_example_testsampleso_Addition_mAdd` in generated header file and  `Java_com_ndkadd_Addition_Addition_mAdd` in .so file is different ?

is that the reason for unsatisfied linker error ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a native method named **mAdd()** declared in your Java class? Most likely, you can find an *exported function* named `Java_blablabla_mAdd` in **libAddition.so**. This blablabla should match the full name of your class. Note that you are not obliged to put your class in the `com.example.testadditionso` package, as generated by default by the IDE. The packages in Android are not sealed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java class is **com.example.testsampleso.Addition**, but the library was built to be used with Java class **com.ndkadd.Addition.Addition**.

You can only call the **mAdd** native method from the Java class with correct name (and package name). This name does not fit your Android package name, but there is no problem with that.

You can add any class with any package name to your APK.