# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using `fmmr.jar` to create thumbnail of a video file from URL. Earlier it was all well with this, but now it gives unsatisfied link error.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217): Process: com.bdcs.corporate.VikramSingh, PID: 17217
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.bdcs.corporate.VikramSingh-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.bdcs.corporate.VikramSingh-1]: findLibrary returned null
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.<clinit>(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.java:120)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at com.bdcs.coporate.videothumbnail.ThumbnailExtractor.createVideoThumbnail(ThumbnailExtractor.java:23)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at com.bdcs.corporate.publicinfo.ListAdapter$1.doInBackground(ListAdapter.java:113)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at com.bdcs.corporate.publicinfo.ListAdapter$1.doInBackground(ListAdapter.java:1)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    01-29 13:27:10.816: E/AndroidRuntime(17217):    ... 4 more
```

This is my libs folder:

[image]

It contains `.so` files but `libavutil.so` is unable to load.

Comment: Can be that you need to have the library for armeabi-v7a instead of armeabi? Check this link as it may be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case

Comment: Hi Luis,it is working ,but it application is getting frozen.

Comment: thanx Luis ,now it's working