# couldn't find "libmynative.so" even though its copied to libs folder(Android NDK)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I successfully copied "libmynative.so" folder to armeabi folder

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: mynative <= helloworld.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: mynative <= jni_entry.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libmynative.so
[armeabi] Install        : libmynative.so =>libs/armeabi/libmynative.so
```

Still I get the following error

```
02-20 01:01:22.949 10851-10851/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.lol.jnihelloworld, PID: 10851
                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lol.jnihelloworld-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmynative.so"
                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                   at com.lol.jnihelloworld.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:19)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1089)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.lol.jnihelloworld;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public native String getNativeMessage();


static {
    System.loadLibrary("mynative");
}


Button btnInvokeJNI;
TextView tvNativeMsg;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btnInvokeJNI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInvokeJni);
    tvNativeMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtJniText);


    btnInvokeJNI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvNativeMsg.setText(getNativeMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

The error indicates to System.loadLibrary("mynative");
I am not able to resolve it.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3nJr.png)

Comment: It *sounds* like you're doing everything right.  SUGGESTION: Read this link for some great troubleshooting tips: [System.loadLibrary(…) couldn't find native library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case).  Please post back what you find.

Comment: What device are you using to run this?

Comment: I am running on my android lollipop device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Android studio, the default jni libraries directory is not `libs`, you have to specify it under gradle build script explicitly.

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

Also, after build finish, you can check if the native libraries are built into your apk.

```
$ unzip -l app-debug.apk |grep mynative
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio make sure your .so are inside a folder "jniLibs" located at app/src/main/ on your project.

So in your project it will look like this.

```
└── ProjectRoot
    └── app
        └── src
            └── main
                └── jniLibs
                    └── armebi
                          └── lib.so
```