# How do I load a native library (.so) from another native library (.so)?

Tags: java, android-ndk, loadlibrary

So, my code right now is like it loads library (say liba.so) from Java-layer and internally liba.so loads libb.so. So, if I have to pack all the libraries inside an APK and install it on a device with no root access then what is the procedure to structure my project in which one load call from Java-layer will load both the libraries, first liba.so (direct call) and then libb.so (second call, nested call, call from liba.so)?

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: In my Java file, I am loading from System.loadLibrary(liba.so) 
And then in liba.so's source file I am using dlopen to open libb.so.

I want to know how will I be able to pack them in an APK such that liba.so call libb.so internally. Right now, I am able to call liba.so from Java-layer but libb.so is not getting called from liba.so

Answer (score 2):

If both liba.so and libb.so are packed into your APK, then the installer will unpack both to the [nativeLibraryDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir).

From Java, loadLibrary() will look in this directory automatically. But dlopen() is not aware of this path. You must provide to dlopen() the full path to the installed libb.so.

Alternatively, you can load libb from Java, then it will be in memory and liba will find it's exported symbols without dlopen().

If you need to understand better the process of packing the libraries into APK, consult [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523384/192373).

Comment: Thanks @alex. That was really helpful link. I have one question though.
If we have libraries in nativeLibraryPath, then do we still need to call `LoadLibrary`. I have verified that and it seems app works fine without explicit loading libraries.

I just load one library and it's dependencies are automatically loaded without any call to LoadLibrary

Comment: @abhiarora that's right, the clumsy behavior that I described 6 years ago has been fixed since then, I don't remember off-hand in which version of Android. Note that this is not a feature of Android Studio or SDK that you use to build your app, but of the OS on the device. So, if you want to support ancient devices, my advice may still be relevant.