# application crash when try to load System.loadLibrary("loader-jni")

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libloader-jni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
        at com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI.<clinit>(LoadJNI.java:15)
        at com.forsale.app.utils.facades.VideoCompressor$getCompressedVideo$retValue$1.invokeSuspend(VideoCompressor.kt:21)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:236)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

I am getting the crash above when try to run my code

```
fun getCompressVideo (video: String) {

        launch (Dispatchers.Main){
            viewModel.mediaViewModel.video = videoCompressor.getCompressedVideo(context, Uri.parse(viewModel.mediaViewModel.video))
        }
    }

override suspend fun getCompressedVideo(context: Context?, video: Uri): String {

            val retValue = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                val inputFile = video.path
                Log.i("AMIRA3000" , inputFile)
                val loadJNI = LoadJNI()

                val workFolder: String = context!!.filesDir.absolutePath

                val outputFile: String = getFileFullName(
                    FilesConstants.VIDEO_FOLDER,
                    String.format(FilesConstants.VIDEO_NAME_FILE_FORMAT, System.currentTimeMillis())
                )

                val complexCommand = arrayOf(
                    "ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", inputFile, "-strict", "experimental", "-s", "320x240", "-r", "25", "-aspect", "4:3", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-movflags", "+faststart", "-ar", "22050", "-b", "2097k", outputFile
                )

                loadJNI.run(complexCommand, workFolder, context)
            }

            return retValue.toString()
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
public final class LoadJNI {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("loader-jni");
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args ffmpeg command
     * @param workFolder working directory 
     * @param ctx Android context
     * @param isValidate apply validation to the command
     * @throws CommandValidationException
     */
    public void run(String[] args, String workFolder, Context ctx, boolean isValidate) throws CommandValidationException {
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "running ffmpeg4android_lib: " + Prefs.version);
        // delete previous log: this is essential for correct progress calculation
        String vkLogPath = workFolder + "vk.log";
        GeneralUtils.deleteFileUtil(vkLogPath);
        GeneralUtils.printCommand(args);

        //printInternalDirStructure(ctx);

        if (isValidate) {
            if (GeneralUtils.isValidCommand(args))
                load(args, workFolder, getVideokitLibPath(ctx), true);
            else
                throw new CommandValidationException();
        }
        else {
            load(args, workFolder, getVideokitLibPath(ctx), true);
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args ffmpeg command
     * @param videokitSdcardPath working directory 
     * @param ctx Android context
     * @throws CommandValidationException
     */
    public void run(String[] args, String workFolder, Context ctx) throws CommandValidationException {
        run(args, workFolder, ctx, true);
    }


    private static void printInternalDirStructure(Context ctx) {
        Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "=printInternalDirStructure=");
        Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "==============================");
        File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getParent());
        analyzeDir(file);
        Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "==============================");
    }

    private static void analyzeDir(File path) {
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG,"Scanning dir: " + path.getAbsolutePath());
            File[] files1 = path.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files1.length; i++) {
                analyzeDir(files1[i]);
            }
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "==========");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }

    private static String getVideokitLibPath(Context ctx) {

        //File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/lib/");
        //analyzeDir(file);

        String videokitLibPath = ctx.getFilesDir().getParent()  + "/lib/libvideokit.so";

        File file = new File(videokitLibPath);
        if(file.exists())  {     
          Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath exits: " + videokitLibPath);
        }
        else {
            Log.w(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath not exits: " + videokitLibPath);
            videokitLibPath = ctx.getFilesDir().getParent()  + "/lib/arm64/libvideokit.so";
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "trying videokitLibPath: " + videokitLibPath);
            file = new File(videokitLibPath);
            if(file.exists())  {
                Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath exits: " + videokitLibPath);
            }
            else {
                Log.w(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath not exits: " + videokitLibPath);
                videokitLibPath = "/data/app/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo-1/lib/arm64/libvideokit.so";
                Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "trying videokitLibPath: " + videokitLibPath);
                file = new File(videokitLibPath);
                if(file.exists())  {
                    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath exits: " + videokitLibPath);
                }
                else {
                    Log.w(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath not exits: " + videokitLibPath);
                    videokitLibPath = "/data/app/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo-2/lib/arm64/libvideokit.so";
                    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "trying videokitLibPath: " + videokitLibPath);
                    if(file.exists())  {
                        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath exits: " + videokitLibPath);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "can't find path of lib");
                    }
                }
            }
        }





        //String videokitLibPath = ctx.getFilesDir().getParent()  + "/lib/arm64/libvideokit.so";

        // only this works on Android M, and the number changes (demo-2, demo-1)
        //String videokitLibPath = "/data/app/com.examples.ffmpeg4android_demo-1/lib/arm64/libvideokit.so";


        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "videokitLibPath: " + videokitLibPath);
        return videokitLibPath;

    }



    public void fExit( Context ctx) {
        fexit(getVideokitLibPath(ctx));
    }

    public native String fexit(String videokitLibPath);

    public native String unload();

    public native String load(String[] args, String videokitSdcardPath, String videokitLibPath, boolean isComplex);
}
```

the file is found in the library

[image]

Comment: The crash happens inside your LoadJNI() method, which you haven't posted. It has nothing to do with Kotlin coroutines.

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: It seems `libloader-jni.so` file is missed.

Comment: @Sergey please check my edit

Comment: libloader-jni.so is a library file, it should be added to the app. When you call `System.loadLibrary("loader-jni");` it tries to load it but can't find. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case

Comment: What is `loader-jni`? Is it part of your own project (i.e. Android + native project)? Are you sure you are correctly including it in your build?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a bunch of `armeabi-v7a` libraries. But the error messages says that the linker is looking for an `arm64-v8a` version of the library. Do you have that version bundled with your app?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late to answer this question but may help someone who is looking for it.
I was also getting the same error and was working on it for couple of days.
i had tried all the possible answers but still was not able to solve them.I was using an old project in which **`jniLibs`** was already present but still i was getting the same error. After a lot of research i got my answer and it worked. this is the link which i followed:

http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

only three things i had to do:

Add this line to your app gradle.build:

> `implementation 'com.netcompss:ffmpeg4android_lib:41.08'`

Add this to your gradle.properties:

> `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

Add this in the application tag in manifest file:

> `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

I hope it may help someone: Good Luck.