# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - wrong directory searched for native libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

In my app I'm using Android NDK to build libraries for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, and x86_64 ABI's.
I'm uploading the libraries as a bundle to google play.

On some devices I'm getting the following error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my-package-name-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package.name-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libc++_shared.so"
```

I checked the content of the uploaded bundle and it definitely contains libc++_shared.so for the above mentioned ABIs.

It seems that the directory that is searched is incorrect `"../lib/arm"`. I didn't add support for obsolete ABIs(mips, armeabi), but I don't remember that there was anything called `"arm"`.

How could I fix this issue?

**Update**:
Specifying the supported ABIs explicitly in gradle file didn't help. I again checked if libc++_shared.so is present inside of the bundle file (for each ABI) before uploading it to play store, and again there were no files missing.

Another strange thing I noticed is that there are many crashes per user (+10/user). I find this a bit strange because without the libraries, the app cannot work (not even start). And if I would start an app that immediately crashes or doesn't work at all, I would uninstall it probably after the first unsuccessful try.

Thanks

Comment: This could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982270/android-application-unable-to-create-soflink-to-native-library-for-64-bit-shared .
Try doing adb shell and dumpsys package packages | grep your_package_name and check what is your legacyNativeLibraryDir/CPU_ARCH .

Comment: legacyNativeLibraryDir is just ending with /lib, which seems correct. Anyway, it's not crashing on my devices. Only on devices I don't have access to.

Comment: @roman did you find a proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you jni builds are being copied to libs instead of jniLibs.
if yes, copy content from libs to jniLibs.

[Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421134/system-loadlibrary-couldnt-find-native-library-in-my-case/27523384#27523384)

Comment: I noticed that when I enable Firebase Crashlytic and I don't specify the target native ABIs explicitly in gradle `(ndk { abiFilters ..})`, the buildsystem creates `armeabi` folder that only contains `libcrashlytics.so` and not my other libraries. 

Can "../lib/arm" directory be actually used for `armeabi`? 

Will have to monitor this for some time to see if I get crashes after my last changes where I specified the exact ABIs in gradle.
Thanks for your suggestions